# Копирование папки и ее содержимого

Tags: c++

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR toPath[MAX_PATH];

std::wcin >> path;
std::wcin >> toPath;

SHFILEOPSTRUCT fos;
ZeroMemory(&fos, sizeof(fos));

fos.wFunc = FO_MOVE;
fos.pFrom = path;
fos.pTo = toPath;
fos.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_SILENT;

if (SHFileOperation(&fos))
    std::cout << "The directory is moved successfully!" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "[ERROR] The directory is not moved!" << std::endl;
```

Входные данные:

```
C:\\new
C:\\newgovno\\

C:\new
C:\newgovno\
```

Не копируется папка.

Comment: Папки `C:\\news\\ ` я на скрине не вижу. А вот `C:\news` - да, есть

Comment: Мне прописывать C:\news в консоль?

Comment: само собой. Зачем Вы там-то «экранируете»? Экранирование нужно лишь в строках, которые Вы записываете в коде программы)

Comment: Записал, как вы сказали, но ничего не копируется.

Comment: @AnT «Люк, я твой папка!»

Comment: @qucals покажите код

Comment: @Kir_Antipov https://imgur.com/a/mhF6ENZ

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nRFIi1G

Comment: @qucals родной, тут принято код (а точнее «минимальный воспроизводимый пример») приводить прямо в тексте вопроса. С картинки (да и ещё на стороннем ресурсе) тут ни у кого желания читать и тем более переписывать нет)

Comment: Добавил код, как просили

Comment: @AnT возможно, вы имели в виду "*клонирование* папки и его содержимого С++"

Comment: @AnT Да, клонирование

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации указано, что члены структуры `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` `pFrom` и `pTo` должны в конце строки содержать **двойной** нуль-терминатор.

Т.е. к введенной строке вам следует добавлять еще один нулевой символ (`'\0'`).

Решение будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
// ...
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR toPath[MAX_PATH];
std::wcin >> path;
std::wcin >> toPath;
path[lstrlen(path) + 1] = '\0';
path[lstrlen(path) + 1] = '\0';
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fos;
ZeroMemory(&fos, sizeof(fos));

fos.wFunc = FO_MOVE;
fos.pFrom = path;
fos.pTo = toPath;
fos.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_SILENT;
// еще один момент
// функция SHFileOperation возвращает 0 в случае успешного выполнения
// и ненулевое значение если операция закончилась неуспешно
if (!SHFileOperation(&fos))
    std::cout << "good\n";
else
    std::cout << "bad\n";
// ...
```

Еще стоит заметить, что в качестве разделителя в пути файловой системы api принимает только `\`, но не `/`.